# Meteor User Account Settings email validation

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor user accounts api to create user accounts.

https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md

How to add email restriction to particular domain such as only `@mydomain.org` so that only those users with the domain will be allowed to log into the system while other users with other domains such as `@gmail.com` would not be able to log into the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this (unfortunately) undocumented `Accounts.config` which is part of `accounts-base`. It allows you to set a email domain restriction for accounts creation. This your app won't allow any accounts to be created that are not part of this domain:

Put the following in server and client startup code to configure the accounts package:

```js
Accounts.config({
  restrictCreationByEmailDomain: 'mydomain.com'
})
```

The source documentation says on this particular option

> `@param {String | Function} options.restrictCreationByEmailDomain` If set to a string, only allows new users if the domain part of their email address matches the string. If set to a function, only allows new users if the function returns true.  The function is passed the full email address of the proposed new user.  Works with password-based sign-in and external services that expose email addresses (Google, Facebook, GitHub). All existing users still can log in after enabling this option. Example: `Accounts.config({ restrictCreationByEmailDomain: 'school.edu' })`.

Source code of the `Account.config`  method: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js#L170

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`accounts-password`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.htm) package to manage user creation and authentication.

With `Accounts.createUser` method you can easily create an user where you can apply any kind of check. In your case add a regex check to make sure the email address comes from your domain before calling the `Account.createUser` method.